# Issue with React Router and Routes not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm facing an issue with React Router where the routes are not rendering correctly. I have defined my routes using the `<Routes>` component and nested `<Route>` components within it. However, I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught Error: A `<Route>` is only ever to be used as the child of
>  element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your `<Route>`
> in a `<Routes>`.
> at invariant (history.ts:480:1)
> at Route (components.tsx:353:1)

> history.ts:480 Uncaught Error: [div] is not a `<Route>` component. All
> component children of `<Routes>` must be a `<Route>` or
> `<React.Fragment>`
> at invariant (history.ts:480:1)
> at components.tsx:643:1

> history.ts:480 Uncaught Error: A `<Route>` is only ever to be used as
> the child of `<Routes>` element, never rendered directly. Please wrap
> your `<Route>` in a `<Routes>`.
> at invariant (history.ts:480:1)
> at Route (components.tsx:353:1)

> history.ts:480 Uncaught Error: [div] is not a `<Route>` component. All
> component children of `<Routes>` must be a `<Route>` or
> `<React.Fragment>`
> at invariant (history.ts:480:1)

I have tried wrapping the `<Route>` components in a `<Routes>` component, but the error persists. Here is the relevant code snippet:

here is the code snipped

```
return (
  <Router>
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className="container container-fluid">
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} exact />
            <Route path="/search/:keyword" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductDetails />} exact />

            <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} exact />

            <Route path="/shipping" element={<ProtectedRoute component={Shipping} />} />
            <Route path="/confirm" element={<ProtectedRoute component={ConfirmOrder} />} exact />
            <Route path="/success" element={<ProtectedRoute component={OrderSuccess} />} />
            {stripeApiKey && (
              <Elements stripe={loadStripe(stripeApiKey)}>
                <Route path="/payment" element={<ProtectedRoute component={Payment} />} />
              </Elements>
            )}

            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
            <Route path="/password/forgot" element={<ForgotPassword />} exact />
            <Route path="/password/reset/:token" element={<NewPassword />} exact />
            <Route path="/me" element={<ProtectedRoute component={Profile} />} exact />
            <Route path="/me/update" element={<ProtectedRoute component={UpdateProfile} />} exact />
            <Route path="/password/update" element={<ProtectedRoute component={UpdatePassword} />} exact />

            <Route path="/orders/me" element={<ProtectedRoute component={ListOrders} />} exact />
            <Route path="/order/:id" element={<ProtectedRoute component={OrderDetails} />} exact />
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>

        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin={true} component={Dashboard} />} exact />
        <Route path="/admin/products" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin={true} component={ProductsList} />} exact />
        <Route path="/admin/product" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin={true} component={NewProduct} />} exact />
        <Route path="/admin/product/:id" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin={true} component={UpdateProduct} />} exact />
        <Route path="/admin/orders" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin={true} component={OrdersList} />} exact />
        <Route path="/admin/order/:id" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin={true} component={ProcessOrder} />} exact />
        <Route path="/admin/users" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin={true} component={UsersList} />} exact />
        <Route path="/admin/user/:id" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin={true} component={UpdateUser} />} exact />
        <Route path="/admin/reviews" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin={true} component={ProductReviews} />} exact />
      </Routes>

      {!loading && (!isAuthenticated || user.role !== 'admin') && <Footer />}
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

Could anyone please help me understand what could be causing this error and how to fix it? I have already checked the React Router documentation, but I'm unable to find a solution. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

## Issues

1. The `Route` component can only be the child of the `Routes` component or another `Route` component in the case of nesting routes.
2. The `Routes` component can only have a `Route` or `React.Fragment` component as a child, the Stripe `Elements` component can't be rendered in the place of a route.

## Solution

- Convert the container `div` JSX into a layout route component that renders an `Outlet` for nested routes to be rendered into.
- Swap the order of `Elements` to directly wrap the route `element` content on the Stripe route.

Example:

```
<Router>
  <div className="App">
    <Header />
    <Routes>
      <Route
        element={(
          <div className="container container-fluid">
            <Outlet />
          </div>
        )}
      >
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/search/:keyword" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductDetails />} />
        <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} exact />
        <Route path="/shipping" element={<ProtectedRoute component={Shipping} />} />
        <Route path="/confirm" element={<ProtectedRoute component={ConfirmOrder} />} />
        <Route path="/success" element={<ProtectedRoute component={OrderSuccess} />} />
        <Route
          path="/payment"
          element={stripeApiKey ? (
            <Elements stripe={loadStripe(stripeApiKey)}>
              <ProtectedRoute component={Payment} />
            </Elements>
          ) : <Navigate to="/" replace />}
        />   
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
        <Route path="/password/forgot" element={<ForgotPassword />} />
        <Route path="/password/reset/:token" element={<NewPassword />} />
        <Route path="/me" element={<ProtectedRoute component={Profile} />} exact />
        <Route path="/me/update" element={<ProtectedRoute component={UpdateProfile} />} />
        <Route path="/password/update" element={<ProtectedRoute component={UpdatePassword} />} />
        <Route path="/orders/me" element={<ProtectedRoute component={ListOrders} />} />
        <Route path="/order/:id" element={<ProtectedRoute component={OrderDetails} />} />
      </Route>

      <Route path="/dashboard" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin component={Dashboard} />} />
      <Route path="/admin/products" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin component={ProductsList} />} />
      <Route path="/admin/product" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin component={NewProduct} />} />
      <Route path="/admin/product/:id" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin component={UpdateProduct} />} />
      <Route path="/admin/orders" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin component={OrdersList} />} />
      <Route path="/admin/order/:id" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin component={ProcessOrder} />} />
      <Route path="/admin/users" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin component={UsersList} />} />
      <Route path="/admin/user/:id" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin component={UpdateUser} />} />
      <Route path="/admin/reviews" element={<ProtectedRoute isAdmin component={ProductReviews} />} />
    </Routes>
    {!loading && (!isAuthenticated || user.role !== 'admin') && <Footer />}
  </div>
</Router>
```